# Deserialzing works in gson-2.1 but not gson-2.4.4

Tags: java, json, gson

I have this snippet:

```
HashMap<String, List<ClassOne>> mappingMap = new HashMap<String, List<ClassOne>>();
String key = "pop";
ClassOne c1 = new ClassOne();
c1.setCategoryName("categoryName");
ArrayList<ClassOne> al = new ArrayList<ClassOne>();
al.add(c1);
mappingMap.put(key, al);
Gson gson = new Gson();
String data = gson.toJson(mappingMap);
HashMap<String, List<ClassOne>> dmm = gson.fromJson(data, new TypeToken<Map<String, List<ClassOne>>>() {}.getType());
```

It when run with the gson-2.1.jar , it works fine. When run with the gson-2.2.4.jar I get the following exception

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap
>   cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap   at com......

Wondering if anyone could explain, or point out what I am doing incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about 2.1, but if it's true that it worked, then Gson must have changed their default `Map` implementation to use when deserializing `Map` types from `HashMap` to `LinkedTreeMap` in gson-2.2.4.

If you want to continue using `HashMap`, specify it in the `TypeToken`.

```
new TypeToken<HashMap<String, List<ClassOne>>>()
```

Comment: +1 - To be more specific, the only reason it worked in the first place would be due to *pure luck* that Gson was using `HashMap` when the `Map` interface was passed in via the `TypeToken`. And now .... it's not.

Comment: yes i believe it was just luck that i found that. Your fix solved the issue.THANKS!

Comment: Even better, use `Map` on both sides: in the parameter type and in the declaration type. That'll keep LinkedTreeMap behind-the-scenes, and that has protection against hash-collision DoS attacks.